# new key/value pair not inserting in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to search for a value exist in multidimensional array, if exist add a new key/value pair. But i am not able to insert the new key/value pair. the multidimensional array $data is shown below.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [num] => +12000000000 [state] => eeee ) 
        [1] => Array ( [num] => +12000000001 [state] => ) )
```

Another normal array $i is

```
Array ( [Sss] => +12000000000 [MS] => +12000000001 [KNum] => +919000000000 )
```

Search for num from $i exist in $data array using the below.

```
foreach($i as $key => $value){
   $s[]= searchForId($value, $data,$key);   //Edited
}


function searchForId($id, $array, $k) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['num'] === $id) {
            //return $key;
            echo "<br>------" . $key;
            echo "<br>------" . $k;
            echo "<br>------" . $id;
            $array[$key]=$k;
            $array[$key]['name']=$k;
            return $array;   //Edited
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried with both the options which mentioned below but not inserting values into the $data multidimensional array. what is wrong here?

```
$array[$key]=$k;
$array[$key]['name']=$k;
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Certainly inserting a key/value pair into an existing associative array _does_ work. So question is, why do you claim otherwise? What _excatly_ does that mean? I suggest you dump the array before and after the insertions and compare. What difference do you see?

Comment: No, new key/value pair is not inserted. I print_r($data) after insert but new key/value pair is not seen. same values after dump the array before and after insertions

Comment: Since you are not passing by reference, and not returning anything from your function, any changes made within the function will not persist outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP function trans parameter by value, not by reference(depreciated), if you want to modify the paremeter, return it.

Comment: I return the array value and captured it in $s[] but there are some repeated values seen. [{"num":"+12000000000 ","state":"eee","name":"Sss"},{"num":"+12000000000 ","status":""}][{"num":"+12000000001","statue":""},{"num":"12000000001","statue":"","name":"MS"}]null